# MS Access - multiple count from same table

Tags: sql, ms-access

First time poster...

I am using access to build a report for alarms from a control system. The list is an export from the alarm utility which needs needs 3 important bits of data:

1. Module - Name of instrument associated with alarm
2. Description - description of the instrument
3. Alarm type - High, High High etc.

I would like to do a top ten of all the alarms but the issue I'm having is that the instrument module contains multiple different types of alarms and I need to filter for each one. I used the group by then count, but it takes all instances of module and does not break it down.

I am not very good at SQL and access and I'm sure its a simple fix.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I you want multiple count from same table you can write the query like below

record  = session.createSQLQuery("select count(village_id),count(date_of_action),  from TABLE_NAME where CONDITION ORDER BY date_of_action DESC" ).list();

```
    if (record  != null && record.size() > 0) {

        for(Object[] obj:(List<Object[]>)record  ){
            int i = 0;
            BigInteger villageCounts = (BigInteger)obj[i];
            BigInteger memberCounts = (BigInteger)obj[++i];
```